# What Installtion is needed before desired state configuration can be used?

Tags: dsc

I want to know what is installed on a bare mental machine (real or virtual) to allow it to be further configured by DSC.
All the demos I have seen already have "something" installed on the target so it can have more things installed with DSC. What has to be installed first and how does it get there.

Answer (score 0):

From [Desired State Configuration Overview for Decision Makers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/decisionmaker) :

> DSC was introduced in Windows Server 2012 R2, it is available for downlevel operating systems via the Windows Management Framework (WMF) package. More information about the WMF can be found on the PowerShell homepage.
>
> DSC can also be used to manage Linux. For more information, see Getting Started with DSC for Linux

So Windows 2012 R2 or greater it is available by default, nothing to install.

If you want to get more advanced and centralise your DSC configurations you could look to install a 'pull server' but this is not required for basic DSC use.  See [Desired State Configuration Pull Service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/pullserver)

Comment: So full local install of a a version of Windows Server or a PXE image install is still needed.  Is there No smaller install bootstrap is available.

Comment: Not sure what your use case is exactly, but DSC is also available in Windows Core.

Comment: Was that helpful? Please accept the answer or provide further feedback